Kibana [version 8.*] status is showing as : Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes
I have installed elasticsearch on my server, its status is showing as active:

[root@dev]# systemctl status elasticsearch
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-04-16 16:51:00 BST;

Here is elasticsearch.yml:
node.roles: [master, data, ingest]
path.data: /data/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
bootstrap.memory_lock: false
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
transport.host: localhost
transport.port: 9300-9400
discovery.type: "single-node"

I have installed kibana as well, which is in active status, but throwing following exception:
[ERROR][elasticsearch-service] Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. security_exception: missing authentication credentials for REST request
Here is kibana.yml:
server.port: 5601
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
server.name: "Kibana"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]

Note that both elasticsearch and kibana are on same server.
And they are installed using ansible role. Elasticsearch is single node only.

Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

You need kibana_system built in user to connect Kibana with Elasticsearch.
So you can add these two lines in your kibana.yml.
Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.17/using-kibana-with-security.html
elasticsearch.username: "kibana_system"
elasticsearch.password: "kibanapassword"

Please write your own kibana_system password. If you do not have any, you can recreate using elasticsearch.
bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u kibana_system

This uses -u (user) tag and resets your password.
Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/reset-password.html
User explanation:

kibana_system:
The user Kibana uses to connect and communicate with Elasticsearch.


There's no such user : kibana_system, However there's a user: kibana. I managed to reset its password. Used the same in kibana.yml. Now kibana has started working & no longer throwing the above mentioned error.
But the catch here is, i cant directly place planetext passwords in kibana.yml. Is there any way to achieve this through ansible??

One way could be saving password to elastic-keystore. you can add the password there: bin/kibana-keystore add elasticsearch.password. If you want to give it another name, you can  pull this password as a variable in kibana.yml: elasticsearch.password: "${my-pass}"

is there any way by which i can include 'bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u kibana_system' in ansible. And then i can push the password in config using kibana.yml.

I am able to change password by including 'bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u kibana' in ansible. I have registered the output. How to use/assign this output value??

you may use cli command to pass values. If you have for example such configuration in kibana.yml: logging.dest:  %{LOG_DIR}    you can use as command line command: bin/kibana --logging.dest=LOG_DIR   Here is the sources: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-set-custom-env-variable-in-kibana-yml/79855  and this https://discuss.elastic.co/t/using-environment-variables-in-kibana-yml/41307

Implemented reset password for user kibana in ansible. And passed the same in kibana.yml solved my issue.
